# BeautifulSoup (bs4) does not find all tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using Python 3.5 and bs4

The following code will not retrieve all the tables from the specified website.  The page has 14 tables but the return value of the code is 2.  I have no idea what's going on.  I manually inspected the HTML and can't find a reason as to why it's not working.  There doesn't seem to be anything special about each table.

```
import bs4
import requests

link = "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/B/BradTo00.htm"

htmlPage = requests.get(link)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlPage.content, 'html.parser')
all_tables = soup.findAll('table')
print(len(all_tables))
```

What's going on?

EDIT: I should clarify.  If I inspect the soup variable, it contains all of the tables that I expected to see.  How am I not able to extract those tables from soup with the findAll method?

Comment: Check whether the table is being loaded via Ajax or not.

Comment: this page use JavaScript to display data but probably all data are in HTML but commented. You may try to use BS to find `comment` tags, or try to use string function (or regex) to find `<!-- ... -->` - and maybe then you could use this string with BS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this page is rendered by javascript, and if you disable the javascrip in you broswer, you will notice that this page only hava two table. 
i recommend to use selenium for this situation.

Comment: I had assumed that I had gotten back the html after all of the javascript and ajax requests had loaded.  When I had inspected the 'soup' variable, all of the tables were there.  Doesn't that prove that I'm retrieving the data after the ajax requests are made?

Comment: requests are not able to do that, but if you use selenium or something like that, and you get a soup that contain all the table, that prove you get data after the page is rendered by javascrip

Comment: I'm still confused because I see all of the tables in the soup.  But anyways, using selenium worked.  Thank you!